# iOS push notifications to large number of users

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, push, apple-push-notifications

I saved users' device tokens in database.
At the time to push notifications,I loaded all device tokens from database,then in a loop,I send push message to one user one time.
Now there are about 300 thousands users,I want to know,is there any other better way?
Thanks

Comment: I would also like to know.  I was curious if I have to create several threads and have each thread process n-users froma queue

Comment: what are you using to push your notifications? we used a server script that implements [forking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(operating_system)). this way you can spawn several forks and send notifications at the same time. this will greatly reduce duration of sending notifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no better way with Apple.  You need to send the same message to each device token.  Services like Parse.com will mask this behind the scenes dirty work for you by letting you broadcast to groups of devices, however you still need to subscribe each device token to the group initially...

So, to answer your question, no there is no better way, you must loop and send to all device tokens :(.

Comment: You could implement long-polling however if your app is not a VOIP or Navigation, or any other kind of app that qualifies to be allowed to run in the background, as soon as the user 'closes' your app, your long polling will no longer work...

EDIT: What some apps do is use long-poll while the app is 'open' and even do it in the background code call (which iOS allows any app to run code in the background for up to 10min after the app is closed).  After your app is allowed to keep the long-polling connection alive, you would signal to your server to start sending push notifications instead.

Comment: Also, my library: PushSharp https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp will let you send out lots of notifications in a very short time.